# How to implement Appender inheriting class in Log4cplus

Tags: inheritance, log4cplus, smtpappender

I want to use **SMTP appender** to send log messages to a given mail addres, using Log4cplus.

Since Log4cplus does not have this appender, I know it is nesessary to extend/inherit the Appender class and implement my own SMTP appender.

Since I haven't seen any example for inheriting and implementing an appender, I would like to ask:
Can anyone share a code example or a reference of inheriting and implementing an appender class?

I will be greatfull for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples of that in the log4cplus source code. You basically need to inherit from `Appender`. Potentially, you might want to register your appender in appenders factory. See `factory.h`.

Comment: Hi wilx, can you please direct me to such an example? I'll be greatefull.